# Dataview RowFilter is changing the Cached Dataset in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, caching, dataset, dataview

I have used this code before in .NET 2.0 and has been performing well for a long time.  I don't know if 4.0 has anything to do with this, but I can't explain the output.  I've distilled it down this code:

```
Sub page_prerender(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
    cache_list()
    Dim dstar As DataSet = Cache("dstallarchives")
    Dim viewar As DataView = dstar.Tables("archive").DefaultView

    Response.Write(viewar.Count & "<br/>") 'output 891
    viewar.RowFilter = "customerid=25"
    Response.Write(viewar.Count & "<br/>") 'output 52

    'clear the dataview, create it fresh from the cache
    viewar = New DataView
    viewar = Cache("dstallarchives").tables("archive").defaultview
    Response.Write(viewar.Count) 'output 52???
End Sub
```

Cache_list inserts a table in a dataset with 891 records.  52 have customerid=25.  You can see above the output I'm getting, when it should be 891 - 52 - 891  I don't normally create that intermediary dstar dataset but create the dataview directly from the cache object.  But now the output makes even less sense to me.  Please help before my laptop suffers a 3 story drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the former code acted the way it did, but I found a solution to the problem.  When declaring the DataView, use the full constructor:

```
viewarchive = New DataView(Cache("dstallarchives").tables("archive"), "", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

If someone could explain this to me, I'd still like to hear it!